# How can I change default print preference to black and white, system wide?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, printing

I would like to make my printer print b&w as default from every application on my mac. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to http://localhost:631/printers
2. Select your printer from the list.
3. Choose Set Default Options from the Administration drop-down.
4. Set the options you would like as default.

Comment: There are two fields for set colour, and changing either causes conflicts.

Comment: @Adripants "Causes conflicts"? Could you expand (with screenshot)?